# Cannot use Parse library in WatchKit Extension (CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, cocoapods, watchkit

I'm attempting to use parse in a WatchKit extension.  I started with a new project (objective-c) and installed the latest Parse (1.7.5) through CocoaPods.  Here is my Podfile.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.3'

target 'WatchBumpTesting' do
        pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.5'
end

target 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit App' do

end

target 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit Extension' do

end
```

I began by following the [tutorial](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-local-data-sharing-for-apple-watch-and-app-extensions/) on their site.  It described how to enable local data sharing, keychain sharing, and app groups.  Here is where I began to encounter issues...

I enabled data sharing in my iOS app no problem.  I imported `<Parse/Parse.h>` in my AppDelegate.h file and was able to complete the setup with the following code.

```
// Enable data sharing in main app.
[Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@”group.com.parse.parseuidemo”];
// Setup Parse
[Parse setApplicationId:@”<ParseAppId>” clientKey:@”<ClientKey>”];
```

Next, I went on to enable data sharing on the WatchKit Extension.  I opened my InterfaceController.h and attempted to import Parse but no luck, the library could not be found.  "Okay - this makes sense, I suppose I have to add it to my Podfile"...so I did! I tried a few updated Podfiles.

V1

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.3'

target 'WatchBumpTesting' do
        pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.5'
end

target 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit App' do

end

target 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit Extension' do
        pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.5'
end
```

V2

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.3'

def shared_pods
        pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.5'
end

target 'WatchBumpTesting' do
        shared_pods
end

target 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit App' do

end

target 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit Extension' do
        shared_pods
end
```

V3

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.3'

link_with 'WatchBumpTesting', 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit Extension'

target 'WatchBumpTesting' do
        pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.5'
end

target 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit App' do

end

target 'WatchBumpTesting WatchKit Extension' do

end
```

All three produced different results, none of which were desired.  V3 would not install the pod.  It stated `[!] Targets with different platforms`.

V1 and V2 resulted in a warning and an error.  The warning...

```
Pods-WatchBumpTesting WatchKit Extension was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods-WatchBumpTesting WatchKit Extension.a' because it doesn't contain platform 'watchsimulator' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'iphonesimulator, iphoneos'
```

The error changed depending on if I imported the library in the extension or not.  The good thing which has come from all of this was that my WatchKit Extension InterfaceController.h file could now see `<Parse/Parse.h>`  However, when I imported it it complained that PFPurchase.h could not find the StoreKit library.

[image]

I attempted to import the library in the WatchKit Extension targets "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" but it could not be found - I'm assuming this is because it is iOS 9 and not WatchKit.  Importing it in the iOS App's target did not fix the problem.

The second error I received was when I left the Podfile as is (V1 and/or V2) but didn't import `<Parse/Parse.h>` or `<Parse.h>` in my InterfaceController.h  This time I recieved...

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-WatchBumpTesting WatchKit Extension-Bolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am at a complete and utter loss.  I've exhausted all options!  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using the latest Xcode 7 Beta as well as CocoaPods 0.37.2

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Sadly not Can Poyrazoğlu, I suppose we'll have to wait for an updated CocoaPods and watchOS 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to specify the watchos platform for CocoaPod configurations targeting WatchOS apps.  Take a look at this for more info:  https://github.com/neonichu/native-watchOS-example?

Comment: Hmmm almost.  I've edited my Podfile as such https://gist.github.com/iiAtlas/52880c865155195a7aa1 but still no luck.  I am recieving a clang error with Parse "ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: I believe this error is from the use_frameworks! line in my Podfile

Comment: I am able to get around this error by omitting use_frameworks!, but sadly I can no longer find the Parse library from my AppDelegate.h

Comment: Header search path's and .xcconfig both look fine to my eye